# error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/extcmd.mod' not found. Entering rescue mode... grub rescue>'

Tags: grub2, grubrescue

I run ubuntu on my laptop from an external drive.

But I turned it off yesterday, and when I tried to turn it back on, this message came up:

```
error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/extcmd.mod' not found.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>'
```

I don't know what to do, can someone please help me?